# two zeros after the decimal point in double

Tags: java

I need this variable to be stored exactly in the form of 1001.00, that is, with two zeros. How to do it. Moreover, it cannot be translated into a string or something like that. It is necessary that the number remains double and at the same time has two zeros after the decimal point.

```
double amount = 1001.00;
```

Comment: Need something else. That is **not** something you can do with [double-precision IEEE-754 floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format). And a Java `double` **is-a** double-precision IEEE-754 floating point number.

Comment: You can't control how a double is stored (although you can control how you print it out later). This sounds a bit like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223467). Can you explain what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Nope - that's not how floating point numbers work. They don't get 'stored' with the precision you want. If you want that to happen (though you shouldn't - why would you want to *diminish* precision?) then `BigDecimal` is what you want. You do your two decimal places thing at *presentation time* when it IS a string

Comment: Then you need to store it as a String.

Comment: This concept is fully implemented by the _[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)_ class.  You can set a decimal scale and a rounding-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is necessary that the number remains double and at the same time has two zeros after the decimal point.

This is impossible, unfortunately.  There is no way whatsoever to do this.

You can print `double` values with a number of digits you choose with `DecimalFormat`.  You can store decimal values to a chosen number of digits with `BigDecimal`.  But a `double` doesn't have a number of digits -- it's just a number.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is impossible ***by design***. Java has IEEE Floating Point numbers. ***By design***, they have only one possible representation. And that representation ***DOES NOT*** allow you to encode the number of extraneous zeroes you want - neither in the front or the back of the number. If they are not extraneous, that is a different story. But what you are asking for are a specific number of extraneous numbers, and that is not possible using floating point.

Now, I assume that you are doing this for presentation reasons. If not, then for what other reason could there be? And if it is for presentation, then the default presentation format is a `String`.

If so, and if you are willing to convert your design into a `String`, then this is a very easy problem to solve. You can simply use [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to get a `String` representation of the number with the desired amount of trailing zeroes.

```java
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Example
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        final DecimalFormat df = new java.text.DecimalFormat("#.00");
        String number;

        number = df.format(1234); //output = "1234.00"
        System.out.println(number);

        //You can also set the rounding mode, in case you want that.
        //Here is the default.
        number = df.format(1234.5678); //output = "1234.57" -- normal rounding
        System.out.println(number);

        //Here is Rounding DOWN
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
        number = df.format(1234.5678); //output = "1234.56" -- rounding DOWN
        System.out.println(number);

        //Try out some other rounding modes with different numbers!

    }

}
```